# link files between django projects in git

Tags: django, git, gitlab

We have multiple projects on our team's account on gitlab.com. 
We want to use some files from one project in another but as links. The reason is that we want the updates to propagate.

If we just copied the code once and the original file was updated, the updates will not be reflected in the file in the other project. So, is there a way to add a a link to a file in project B to a project A? 
So, I can use it as a package in my project and at the same time keep it updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to link a file in one project to keep both projects updated at the same time.

It can become a mess if you start to modify files from project A linked to project B on project B, and the project A starts to crash.

You might want to create a package for some apps from project A to be able to reuse it on project B.

From Django documentation:

> Python packaging refers to preparing your app in a specific format that can be easily installed and used. Django itself is packaged very much like this.

On example it uses [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) to create the packages starting the package name with **django-**. And you can *install* and *uninstall* it with `pip`.

This [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/reusable-apps/) can guide you how to create a Python package for your Django app.

I believe that is the best way to do what you want to do, once you will test the modifications on project A, before using it on project B.

Comment: Well, we have a models file in one app in project A. We want to use the same models in an app in project B. 
But the team of project A might update the models file over time. We want to make a symlink so that these updates to the models are reflected to project B. 

If we package it once then that's it. If team A updated the models file then we need to package and import it again.

Comment: The way I see it, if you do a symlink it will spend a big amount of time from the team, once a symlink to keep the files updated will need to be set up for each environment, because each developer has his own directories, so you cannot work with a generic solution. Packaging your models seems to be the more reliable way to work with the same files to many projects. That [tutorial](http://pythoncentral.io/package-python-django-application-reusable-component/) is also good.

Comment: but if I did that. How do I make migrations for the imported models? I mean django makes migrations for models files in each app in the project. Now, I don't have a models file for that app. It is an imported package.

Comment: but if I did that. How do I make migrations for the imported models? I mean django makes migrations for models files in each app in the project. Now, I don't have a models file for that app. It is an imported package.